# Выключить столкновение между определёнными объектами

Tags: unity3d, 2d

Unity2D, нужно, чтобы объект сталкивался только с одним collider'ом и проходил через все остальные.

Comment: образец исправления вопроса: я пробовал так, делал то, хотел нажать сюда, но почему-то происходит не так, как я хотел, а вот так: *скриншот*. здесь ничего не решают, а лишь подталкивают к решению.

Answer (score 2):

Всё зависит от типа коллайдеров и т.п. В общем случае у ваших объектов есть слой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках физики (Edit -> Project settings -> Physics 2D) настройте матрицу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно и хаком из кода добиться результата:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    // или по тегу смотреть collision.gameObject.tag
    if (collision.gameObject.layer == "theobjectToIgnore") {
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(theobjectToIgnore.collider, collider);
    }
}
```